# Are two oppositely orientated circles homotopic to each other?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let's consider two circles on a complex plane with equations
$$\gamma_1(t)=e^{2\pi it}$$
$$\gamma_2(t)=e^{-2\pi it}$$
for $0\leq t\leq 1$.

These two circles have the opposite orientation. But the question arises: Are they homotopic to each other? At first thought, they are: both are homotopic to a point. Nevertheless, as given in [this paper](https://people.math.gatech.edu/%7Ecain/winter99/ch5.pdf),

> A homotopy between $C_1$ and $C_3$ is not easy to construct—in fact, it is not possible!

where $C_1$ is given beforehand by $2e^{i2\pi t}$ and $C_3$ by $4^{-i2\pi t}$. From this, we can deduce that they are not homotopic. However, one page later, there is an exercise,

> A region $D$ is said to be simply connected if every closed curve in $D$ is contractible to a
> point in $D$. Prove that any two closed curves in a simply connected region are homotopic in $D$.

Since the set of complex numbers is simply connected, then *any two closed curves [...] are homotopic in $D$ [here $\mathbb{C}$]*.

I am also acquainted with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3913073/why-are-circles-of-opposite-directions-not-homotopic-to-each-other) question. According to this question, two opposite circles are indeed not homotopic to each other. Unfortunately, those answers don't seem to answer my question.

What is then the truth? Are two oppositely orientated circles homotopic to each other?

Comment: It depends on the region. $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are homotopic in $\Bbb C$, but not in the annular region $D = \{ 1 < |z| < 5 \}$ considered in that paper.

Comment: @MartinR I am very sorry; totally missed that out. Thank you :) I should have read the whole paragraph. I will add an answer as a reference for future readers.