How to understand the inverse loop in the fundamental group?
I'm struggling to build an intuitive picture of the inverse of a loop in the fundamental group.
Is there an intuitive way to see that the if I start from a point $x$ of a topological space an travel back to $x$ via a loop $l_1$ and then I return to $x$ via a loop $l_2$ which is just the reverse of $l_1$, then the combination of $l_1$ and $l_2$ can be continuously deformed to the point $x$?

Have you tried doing it with a rubber band or string around your finger? The composition of a loop and its inverse is like wrapping a rubber band around your finger without 'opening it', i.e., nothing goes through the hole in the middle of the rubber band.

In my opinion it's actually less confusing to consider the more general question of what happens if you take $\ell$ to be a path between any two points $x$ and $y$, not just a loop from a point $x$ to itself. Then the inverse $\ell^{-1}$ is given by the reverse path, which now goes from $y$ to $x$. This is easier to visualize because everything is more spread out, and it's clearer what's going on because $x$ and $y$ are playing two different roles in the argument that are now being distinguished more clearly.
It's also easier to visualize if you don't think of $\ell^{-1}$ as being exactly the reverse path but a path homotopic to it and slightly offset. This lets you visualize the compositions $\ell^{-1} \circ \ell$ and $\ell \circ \ell^{-1}$ as thin loops instead of having to deal with the fact that the path and the reverse path overlap.  I really should draw a picture here but I'm not sure what the most convenient way to do it is.
Now the homotopy is given by "slurping the loop up," as they say. Again ideally I would somehow have an animated .gif here that shows this. Probably someone has made one already. You can think of it like this: $\ell_1$ is some kind of long journey from city $x$ to city $y$, and $\ell_2$ is the reverse journey back home from city $y$ to city $x$. The homotopy is given by getting tired and going home early: at each point in the homotopy you stop traveling a little earlier before you actually make it to city $y$ and just trace your steps back to city $x$, until eventually you haven't gone on a journey at all.
And to get the fundamental group on the nose you take $y = x$.
Edit: Okay, here's a quick and dirty drawing in jspaint. I forgot to label them but the path on the left going up is $\ell$ and the path on the right going down is $\ell^{-1}$:

This is a contracting homotopy for $\ell^{-1} \circ \ell : x \to x$ and the contracting homotopy for $\ell \circ \ell^{-1} : y \to y$ is the same idea but slurping up to $y$.

 Formally we are describing here how to take inverses in the fundamental groupoid. This contains inverses in the fundamental group as a special case.


Thanks for this, I just found something similar here, but essentially the same! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3913073/why-are-circles-of-opposite-directions-not-homotopic-to-each-other
